# Multiple radio buttons getting selected

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, jradiobutton

I have two radio buttons made in java. The problem is they are not linked together i.e. they both can be selected at the same time. How do i achieve link between them?

Comment: you need to read about radio button groups. BTW What ide are you using?

Comment: Hey, was wondering if the answer below helped you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need this;

```
        //Create three radio buttons   
        JRadioButton aButton = new JRadioButton("A",true);
        JRadioButton bButton = new JRadioButton("B");
        JRadioButton cButton = new JRadioButton("C");

        //Create a ButtonGroup object, add buttons to the group
        ButtonGroup myButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        myButtonGroup.add(aButton);
        myButtonGroup.add(bButton);
        myButtonGroup.add(cButton);

        //Display radio buttons
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        getContentPane().add(aButton);
        getContentPane().add(bButton);
        getContentPane().add(cButton);
        setSize(250,100);
        setTitle("Swing Radio Buttons");
        setVisible(true);
```

Let me know, if helped.

Answer (score -2):

Set the same `name` attribute
[Radio example](http://jsfiddle.net/gp4bj/)

```
<input id="hello" type="radio" name="greet">
<label for="hello">hello</label>
<input id="hi" type="radio" name="greet">
<label for="hi">hi</label>
<hr />
<input id="all" type="radio" name="who">
<label for="all">world!</label>
<input id="one" type="radio" name="who">
<label for="one">you</label>
```

Comment: i said in java, what you suggested is in html

Comment: guess he is talking about java swing!

Comment: In that case you're looking for this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html